# g++: error: <descriptive name>: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

When I am using while loop, vscode will be unable to run my code...
Platform: Windows 10
Compiler: Visual Studio Code and Powershell Core
Language: C++

Not using while loop, then it works, but I need while loop to run my program again.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int replay = 0;
    int input;

    while(input == replay)
    {
        //Creating variables to store
        string celebrity = "Keeves Reeves";
        string guess;

        //Prompt the user
        cout << "Guess this celebrity: He acted as John Wick" << endl;
        getline(cin, guess);


        //Check the answer by using switch statement

        if(guess == celebrity){
            cout << "Congratulations! You are right" << endl;
            input = 3;
        } else if(guess != celebrity)
            cout << "Whoops, that not the right answer..." << endl;
            cout << "If you want to try again, enter '0' to replay, enter '1' to view the answer: ";
            cin >> input;
            if(input = 1){
                cout << "The celebrity was " << celebrity << " ." << endl;
            }
    }

    //Break from while loop
    cout << "Thank you for playing. The end." << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0; } ```

D:\Programming Files\C++\vscode>cd "d:\Programming Files\C++\vscode\" && g++ Guess The Celebrity2.cpp -o Guess The Celebrity2 && "d:\Programming Files\C++\vscode\"Guess The Celebrity2
g++: error: Guess: No such file or directory
g++: error: The: No such file or directory
g++: error: Celebrity2.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: The: No such file or directory
g++: error: Celebrity2: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

****NOTE THAT: DO NOT BE LIKE ME, THIS ERROR OCCURS ONLY BECAUSE I PUT SPACE ON MY FILE NAME!!! HOPE THIS HELPS!!!
````

Comment: Don't put spaces in file names

Comment: What is the value of `input` when your code reaches the condition of the while loop? You have undefined behaviour. Also pay attention to warnings `if(input = 1)` is always `true`, because `=` is assignment not comparison

Comment: i am certain that you get the same errors without the while loop...

Comment: @StoryTeller Or put them in quotes.

Comment: @KenY-N - It's hard to have automated tools do it. Some fail and there is no fixing them. Better not have the spaces at all.

Comment: Oh, and you are missing curly brackets around your `else if` block, and pay attention to compiler warnings about assignments in `if` statements.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 No, if I removed the while loop, it works magically, such as if statements only, or hello world.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried, I removed the using namespace std; and use std:: instead but still, the same problem...

Comment: You misunderstood my comment I'm afraid. I did not say not to use **namespaces** (that's another issue). I said that your filename has **spaces** in it.

Comment: @KenY-N Yea, you are right, I am missing a curly bracket, but still, after I added it to the code and save it, I still got the same warning...

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh yea, you are right, now the warning is gone but the new problem is it instantly jump to //Break from while loop ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your call of the application and compile calls in quotes. It has nothing to do with your code at all:

```
g++ "Guess The Celebrity2.cpp" -o "Guess The Celebrity2" && "d:\Programming Files\C++\vscode\Guess The Celebrity2"
```

There are several errors in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int replay = 0;
    int input;

    while(int input >= replay)
    {
        //Creating variables to store
        string celebrity = "Keeves Reeves";
        string guess;

        //Prompt the user
        cout << "Guess this celebrity: He acted as John Wick" << endl;
        getline(cin, guess);


        //Check the answer by using switch statement
        if(guess == celebrity){
            cout << "Congratulations! You are right" << endl;
            input = 3;
        } else if(guess != celebrity){
            cout << "Whoops, that not the right answer..." << endl;
            cout << "If you want to try again, enter '0' to replay, enter '1' to view the answer: ";
            cin >> input;

            if(input = 1){
                cout << "The celebrity was " << celebrity << " ." << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    //Break from while loop
    cout << "Thank you for playing. The end." << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

First input isn't initialized. Second you declare a variable and then compare it to replay (you overwrite input). Third, in your last if statement, you set input to 1, isntaead of comparing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int replay = 0;
    int input = 0;

    while(input == replay)
    {
        //Creating variables to store
        string celebrity = "Keeves Reeves";
        string guess;

        //Prompt the user
        cout << "Guess this celebrity: He acted as John Wick" << endl;
        cin.ignore(); 
        getline(cin, guess);


        //Check the answer by using switch statement
        if(guess == celebrity){
            cout << "Congratulations! You are right" << endl;
            input = 3;
        } else if(guess != celebrity){
            cout << "Whoops, that not the right answer..." << endl;
            cout << "If you want to try again, enter '0' to replay, enter '1' to view the answer: ";
            cin >> input;

            if(input == 1){
                cout << "The celebrity was " << celebrity << " ." << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    //Break from while loop
    cout << "Thank you for playing. The end." << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wait, but like how? I tried to remove the while loop and it works, but if I add it back to the quotes, it doesn't, plus, when I tried to do the hello world, it works either, why? Please help, I have been struggled with this problem for weeks...

Comment: Your compile statement is wrong. It has nothing to do with your source code

Comment: An error could be, that you use unitialized input, in your first while loop `input == result`. You should set `int input = 0`, so that you enter the while loop

Comment: Now there's a new problem which is that warning is gone but the new problem is it instantly jump to //Break from while loop ...

Link: cpp.sh/7tstv

Comment: @FlashSonic526 see my edits, and you should check your getline statement

Comment: Oh, so you can cin a variable that is already assigned? Btw, tkx for helping :)